# Out of Memory exception while wrting 300dpi Images

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a requirement that to create a image with 300DPI, but during the composition of image, like addding the resources (font, images) I am getting out of memory exception.

```
using (Bitmap pg = new Bitmap(GetPixelsFromInches(float.Parse(pageWidth), dpi, actualDpi), GetPixelsFromInches(float.Parse(pageHeight), dpi, actualDpi)))
{
    pg.SetResolution(float.Parse(dpi), float.Parse(dpi));

    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(pg);
    gr.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    System.Drawing.Rectangle pgRect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, pg.Width, pg.Height);
    SolidBrush solidWhite = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
    gr.FillRectangle(solidWhite, pgRect);


    currentPageDisplayed = xNode.Attributes["id"].Value;

    foreach (XmlElement xElement in xNode)
    {
        //Here I am writing each elements, like texts or images.
        DrawImageForElements(xElement, , dpi, actualDpi);

    }


    MemoryStream myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    //pg.Save(myMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
    String filename=@"c:\images\" + currentPageDisplayed + "+.png";
    pg.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);



    myMemoryStream.Dispose();
    gr.Dispose();
    pg.Dispose();
}
```

Please suggest if there is any other better option!!

Comment: What about sticking some extra memory in your PC?

Comment: I have many elements in the image, as it keep drawing the image size is in the memory is growing, e.g.: when i draw image with size of 300DPI, for 11x15 feet size. Its really quite huge. I was wondering if there is any other option i can keep it in file and write on it??

Comment: Could you be more precise about the file size (KB written to the disk) for the biggest image you can save for example? Some images are just too big to fit in memory. And could you post the exception stack trace?

Comment: What do you need this humongous resolution for? Are the source images anywhere near this detail? Are they several gigabytes large too? You will have to load them in memory too... It sounds like your requirements have been set by someone who have no idea of the consequences or what they actually need.

Comment: This image is used for event poster kind of things, since image is quite large. as we create the bitmap and addition text or image. I am having the issues

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic options here that I see.

1. Get a wider architecture.  You'll probably need to do this on an x64 machine with plenty of swap space.  A 24-bit pixmap of those dimensions would take up 300 × 300 × 12 × 12 × 11 × 15 × 3 = 6,415,200,000 bytes of memory, which is within reason on an x64 machine, but larger than the virtual memory space an x86 is capable of addressing.
2. Banding or tiling.  Create a series of smaller pixmaps, one at a time, each corresponding to some subsection of the image and render that portion.  (Banding would imply strips from one side of the image to the other, while tiling chops along both dimensions.)  I'm not entirely sure how you'd go about stitching those pieces together given the tools in the `System.Drawing.**` toolbox, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, The problem is i need to work on the image like adding additional text and images to it. So is there any better option working on it than loading it into the memory??

Comment: Not much that I can think of, unless you're willing to look outside the .Net standard library or else work on the image in sections that aren't saved on disk as one large image.